# How do I seperate date and time from this below code can anybody help me

Tags: java, date-format

```
String pickup = Date Format. get Date Time Instance(
                    Date Format. SHORT, Date Format. SHORT).format(
                    tree.pickup);
```

gives an output like `3/21/15 5:58 AM`. 
I'm trying to do output like `date 3/21/15 and time 5:58 AM`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: String pickupTime = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(
      DateFormat.SHORT, DateFormat.SHORT).format(
      tre.pickupTime);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format the date value using [DateFormat.getDateInstance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#getDateInstance(int)) and [DateFormat.getTimeInstance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#getTimeInstance(int)) separately

For example...

```
Date date = new Date();
String datePart = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT).format(date);
String timePart = DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT).format(date);

String dateAndTime = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, DateFormat.SHORT).format(date);

System.out.println("datePart = " + datePart);
System.out.println("timePart = " + timePart);
System.out.println("dateAndTime = " + dateAndTime);
```

Which outputs

```
datePart = 21/03/15
timePart = 6:46 PM
dateAndTime = 21/03/15 6:46 PM
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code also, try to use date time formats.

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;


public class J2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DateFormat f1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
        DateFormat f2 = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:m:s:a");
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        String date = f1.format(cal.getTime());
        String time = f2.format(cal.getTime());
        System.out.println(date);
        System.out.println(time);
    }

}
```

Comment: yeah thanks its working dude but small help it display whole with seconds also but how can i access this format as output 5:58 AM

Comment: I think if you use DateFormat.getDateInstance and DateFormat.getTimeInstance and pass it SHORT, you'll get the same format as the OP is trying to use...

Comment: DateFormat f2 = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:m a"); try to use this. and refer some date time formatting in java

Comment: Don't forget, based on the local, the date/time format can change ;)

Comment: how can i format that date to MM/dd/yy like 03/21/15

Comment: use this format.  first you may try understand the format.then this will be very easy for you .  DateFormat f1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/YY");

Comment: @MadProgrammer  yes indeed ... :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
   String pickup = Date Format. get Date Time Instance( Date Format. SHORT, Date Format. SHORT).format(tree.pickup);

        System.out.println("Date: " + date.substring(0, pickup.indexOf(' ')));
        System.out.println("Time: " + date.substring(pickup.indexOf(' ') + 1));
```

Comment: its not problem and try this code and let me know if you got any error

Comment: @RameshKumar, it's an example. You're already getting the right value you just want to split it. Sometimes you have to do a little on your own.

Comment: The problem is, as I see it, the format is actually unknown, while very unlikely, it's still possible for a format to have a space in it beyond the separator you are trying to split on. Just saying ;)